# Aggregate query in trigger

Tags: trigger, soql, query, aggregate

I am using the following query in beforeUpdate and after insert:

```
SELECT OwnerId ownerIdVal, Count(Id) oppCount 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE  OwnerId IN: ownerIdSet 
AND lastmodifieddate > 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
AND StageName IN:oppStatusSet
GROUP BY OwnerId
```

Will Salesforce not make it non-selective since it is having a WHERE clause on OwnerId? I tried this in fullcopy sandbox and not hitting any error. Please let me know if you see any issues with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query certainly could be made non-selective, if either `ownerIdSet` or `oppStatusSet` contain a `null` value. Another issue to worry about is ownership skew. If you have one user who owns tens of thousands of records and they get included in your filter collection, you may again run into selectivity issues.

Comment: Adrian, Thanks for the reply.I tried this in fullcopy sandbox having almost same number of records and did not see issues. So any idea if I will hit litmits in production?

Comment: I already laid out the main concerns you need to watch out for. Whether your production behavior will match what you observed during functional testing will depend entirely on your QA rigor. You could try to run it by passing a record collection which will result in your top 200 record owners being in the `ownerIdSet` and that will give you the absolute worst case.

Comment: @Krishna OwnerId is indexed, so as long as your ownerIdSet does not contain null, you should *probably* be okay. Consider adding a LIMIT clause to reduce the odds.

Comment: @sfdcfox Don't `LIMIT` clauses get pretty funky with aggregate queries?

Comment: @sfdcfox if I add LIMIT, I feel that I will not get the proper count of opptys per owner. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried to run the following query in the dev console and tried to see the cost in Query Plan and it seems more than 3. Doesn't this make my query non-selective?Select OwnerId ownerIdVal,StageName stgName, Count(Id) oppCount  FROM Opportunity  WHERE  OwnerId != null   GROUP BY OwnerId,StageName. But according to the documentation, since OwnerId is indexed, it will be a selective query. Please help.

Comment: @Krishna please do not ask new questions via comments. Note threat negative filters such as `!=` increase the cost.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Great answer. I removed the != and used IN('OpptyId') and the cost came to 0.0007 for index on Owner Id and 0.3 for full table scan